SwiftUI Xcode project - Can I change the struct name in the automatically generated file whose name is the app's name?
Suppose I create a new Xcode project of SwiftUI with app name "ExampleApp", then Xcode automatically generates a file ExampleAppApp.swift that contains the following code:
@main
struct ExampleAppApp: App {
    ...
}

Can I change the name of this file and the struct, such as changing it to ExampleApp.swift  and struct ExampleApp: App ? If so, do I also need to modify any other place in the project?

Yes, you can change the struct name and/or the file name, and you don't need to make any additional changes.
All that is important is the @main attribute, and that it is attached to a struct that conforms to App.
The Swift compiler automatically looks for types with a @main attached, and sets the entry point of the program to be the main method of that.
In the case of SwiftUI, this would be App.main(), which your conforming struct gets for free. When this main method is called, all the SwiftUI lifecycle stuff starts up and that's how your SwiftUI app gets started.
However, if you have a file called "main.swift", that will automatically be set as the entry point. Putting a @main in that file is an error, so keep that in mind when renaming your files. For more details, see See SE-0281.
